# Partial View and ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to update Partial View via ajax, but it does not work. Look at this model class:

```
   public class LogOnModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

        public bool IsLoggedIn { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

the following view:

```
@model ITW2012Mobile.ViewModels.LogOnModel
<div id='LogOn' style="background-color: White;">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("LogOnAjax", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "LogOn", OnSuccess = "logInComplete" }))
    { 
        ITW2012Mobile.ViewModels.LogOnModel m = Model;
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsLoggedIn)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReturnUrl)
        <div>
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

and the following controller class:

```
public ActionResult LogOnAjax(LogOnModel model)
{
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                model.IsLoggedIn = true;
                model.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Home"); 
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return PartialView("PartialViewAjaxLogOn", model);
    }
    else
    {
        return PartialView("PartialViewLogOut");
    }
}
```

even when username/password are correct and IsLoggedIn = true and ReturnUrl!=empty view shows empty fields for these variables (but debugger shows values inside). Why and how to make it correctly?

Comment: note your comment above says '// If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form' and yet, you have nothing to stop processing after model.returnUrl, so the comment isnt correct based on your code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing the values you are modifying in your action from modelstate or if you use them in html helpers the old values will be used:

```
ModelState.Remove("IsLoggedIn");
model.IsLoggedIn = true;
ModelState.Remove("ReturnUrl");
model.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Home");
```

Also bear in mind that upon successful authentication and cookie emission you should not display a view (partial in your case). You should redirect so that the authentication cookie is sent by the client on the subsequent request. You should redirect to the return url. But since you are doing this using AJAX you should probably send some indication to the client that the authentication was successful so that you can redirect on the client.

Comment: it really helped me, but I don't understand why. Model value is view is the same for both cases - for case with clear model state and without. Why and how view know that need to update values?

Comment: @John, that's because Html helpers such as TextBoxFor, HiddenFor, ... first look at modelstate when binding their values and after that in the model. This is by design. So if you intend to modify the value of something that is already posted and part of the modelstate you will have to remove it from this modelstate if you want the html  helpers in the subsequent view to use the modified value instead of the original value that was part of the POST request.